# How can I avoid recompiling a specific template function each time I compile my project?

Tags: c++, templates, explicit-instantiation

Say I have a file `foo.hpp` with a template

```
template<int a>
void foo()
{
    // Complex function
}
```

which I use in my `main.cpp`:

```
#include "foo.hpp"

int main()
{
    // quickly compiled code
    // ...

    foo<3>();

    // more quickly compiled code
}
```

Now each time I compile my project after changing `main.cpp`, `foo<3>()` needs to be compiled again, even though it doesn't change.
The vast majority of the compile time is spent compiling `foo<3>()` in my case, so avoiding this is critical.

I would like to compile my project in two steps:

1. Compile `foo<3>()`. This takes long but I only do it once.
2. Compile `main.cpp`. This is now fast because `foo<3>()` is already compiled.

How can I achieve this behavior? I tried doing explicit instantiation in a different file and compiling this first, but `main.cpp` still takes the same time to compile.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:
Clarification of what I tried using explicit instantiation:

Create a new file `precompiled.cpp`:

```
#include "foo.hpp"

template void foo<3>();
```

Then tried compiling this first with `g++ -c precompiled.cpp` and afterwards, compile `main.cpp` using `g++ precompiled.o main.cpp`.
But this instantiates `foo<3>()` again in step 2, which I want to avoid.

Comment: what did you do exactly when you tried explicit instantiation in a different file?

Comment: frankly, I am not sure if I do understand the question. If it is always `foo<3>`  but never `foo<42>` then you do not need to instantiate the template in `main`. Just call `foo()`. If it is different numbers, you need to recompile

Comment: To clarify: I have some `main`, which I compile. Then I change something above the line `foo<3>()`, so `main` needs to be compiled again. This is where I want to avoid having to compile `foo<3>()` again as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing `extern template void foo<3>();` in the header, after the definition of `foo`.

Comment: That's interesting. I never saw this in our code before. Does this "trick" have a name? Is it commonly used? Is it a dirty hack or "clean code"?

Comment: @ThomasWeller This is [*explicit instantiation declaration*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Explicit_instantiation), as opposed to *explicit instantiation definition* (which is the same thing but without `extern`, which must be used in a .cpp file in addition to this, as OP already does). I haven't seen anybody call this a hack. You you can use it to improve build times (as OP wants to do) or to expose templates from shared libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Templates need to be defined in headers (`.hpp`) and instantiated in compilation units (`.cpp`). Unlike regular classes, you cannot declare the function in a header and define it in a compilation unit, which would result in the compilation behaviour you expect: only recompile the function when it's instantiation changes.

I suggest wrapping all calls to your template in a separate `.cpp` and wrap those calls in functions that will be called from `main.cpp`. This way, you may modify other areas of `main.cpp` without recompiling `foo`. However `foo` will be recompiled if you change how you use it in the other unit.

Example:
`foo3.cpp`:

```
#include "foo.hpp"

void foo3() {
    foo<3>();
}
```

`foo3.hpp`:

```
#pragma once

void foo3();
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "foo3.hpp"

int main()
{
    // quickly compiled code
    // ...

    foo3();

    // more quickly compiled code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot avoid instantiating `foo<3>` if you are using a function. Use this instead:

```cpp
template<int a>
struct foo
{
    void operator()() {
        //complex code here
    }
};
```

Make a file say named `bar.hpp` with the following code

```cpp
#include "foo.hpp"
struct foo_3 {
    static foo<3> fooinst = foo<3>();
    void operator()() {
        foo_3::fooinst();
    }
};
```

And then use `bar.hpp` (you are ALLOWED to precompile it returns a `.gch` file. Though I'm puzzled why you insist using the template.